# pipenv install and lock fails every time - on new install of Mac OS Ventura

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv

I'm trying to set up a new environment and Ive run into an issue with PIPENV.

Pipenv will create the virtual env, but when I try to install *any* package using the command `pipenv install <package>` the
install and the lock fails - see an example of the traceback below.

I can bypass the package install issue with `pipenv run pip install <package>`
but even after that, the lock will still fail.

- I've tried multiple different versions of pipenv, no difference.
- I've tried multiple different versions of python (3.10, 3.11, 3.12)
- My copy of pipenv is installed using pip (not home-brew).
- `pipenv lock --pre` fails with the same error
- Everything was working perfectly on previous environment (Mac OS Mojave)

I've read through the tracebacks, but I can't figure out what's going wrong.
The only variable here is the new OS (Ventura), but not sure what
about it could be causing the problem.

```
Installing requests...
Resolving requests...
Added requests to Pipfile's [packages] ...
✔ Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
⠸ Locking...False
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:[present-rich] python setup.py egg_info exited with 1
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 645, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 612, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
[ResolutionFailure]:       ^^^^^^^^
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 592, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 892, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, internal_resolver = actually_resolve_deps(
[ResolutionFailure]:       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 665, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 442, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv run pip install <requirement_name> to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the versions actually installed in the virtualenv.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: metadata generation failed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 58, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 209, in install
    do_install(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 297, in do_install
    raise e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 281, in do_install
    do_init(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/routines/install.py", line 672, in do_init
    do_lock(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/routines/lock.py", line 65, in do_lock
    venv_resolve_deps(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 833, in venv_resolve_deps
    c = resolve(cmd, st, project=project)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 702, in resolve
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!")
RuntimeError: Failed to lock Pipfile.lock!


(test_project) bash-3.2$ pipenv graph
requests==2.31.0
├── certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2023.7.22]
├── charset-normalizer [required: >=2,<4, installed: 3.3.0]
├── idna [required: >=2.5,<4, installed: 3.4]
└── urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<3, installed: 2.0.6]
```

##############################

Here is the output of `pipenv --support`

$ pipenv --support

Pipenv version: `'2023.10.3'`

Pipenv location: `'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv'`

Python location: `'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10'`

OS Name: `'posix'`

User pip version: `'23.2.1'`

user Python installations found:

PEP 508 Information:

```
{'implementation_name': 'cpython',
 'implementation_version': '3.10.11',
 'os_name': 'posix',
 'platform_machine': 'arm64',
 'platform_python_implementation': 'CPython',
 'platform_release': '22.6.0',
 'platform_system': 'Darwin',
 'platform_version': 'Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: Fri Sep 15 13:41:28 PDT '
                     '2023; root:xnu-8796.141.3.700.8~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T6020',
 'python_full_version': '3.10.11',
 'python_version': '3.10',
 'sys_platform': 'darwin'}
```

System environment variables:

- `TERM_PROGRAM`
- `PIP_PYTHON_PATH`
- `TERM`
- `SHELL`
- `TMPDIR`
- `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT`
- `TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION`
- `TERM_SESSION_ID`
- `USER`
- `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`
- `__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING`
- `VIRTUAL_ENV`
- `PIPENV_ACTIVE`
- `PATH`
- `__CFBundleIdentifier`
- `PWD`
- `LANG`
- `PYTHONFINDER_IGNORE_UNSUPPORTED`
- `XPC_FLAGS`
- `PS1`
- `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`
- `XPC_SERVICE_NAME`
- `HOME`
- `SHLVL`
- `LOGNAME`
- `PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK`
- `VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT`
- `_`

Pipenv–specific environment variables:

- `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT`: `1`
- `PIPENV_ACTIVE`: `1`

Debug–specific environment variables:

- `PATH`: `/Users/username/Documents/Github/test_project/.venv/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Components:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin`
- `SHELL`: `/bin/bash`
- `LANG`: `en_US.UTF-8`
- `PWD`: `/Users/username/Documents/Github/test_project`
- `VIRTUAL_ENV`: `/Users/username/Documents/Github/test_project/.venv`

---

Contents of `Pipfile` ('/Users/username/Documents/Github/test_project/Pipfile'):

```ini
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
aiohttp = "==3.8.1"
attr = "==0.3.1"
attrs = "==21.4.0"
blinker = "==1.4"
brotli = "==1.0.9"
ca-certs-locater = "==1.0"
click = "==8.0.4"
configparser = "==5.2.0"
cryptography = "==36.0.1"
cython = "==0.29.28"
dl = "==0.1.0"
docutils = "==0.18.1"
grpc-status = "==1.0.0"
htmlparser = "==0.0.2"
ipython = "==8.3.0"
ipywidgets = "==7.7.0"
jinja2 = "==3.1.2"
jnius = "==1.1.0"
keyring = "==23.5.0"
lockfile = "==0.12.2"
lxml = "==4.8.0"
numpy = "==1.22.2"
oauth2client = "==4.1.3"
ordereddict = "==1.1"
pillow = "==9.1.0"
pyopenssl = "==22.0.0"
pytest = "==7.0.1"
pyu2f = "==0.1.5"
railroad = "==0.5.0"
simplejson = "==3.17.6"
sphinx = "==4.5.0"
toml = "==0.10.2"
tornado = "==6.1"
unicodedata2 = "==14.0.0"
win-inet-pton = "==1.1.0"
xmlrpclib = "==1.0.1"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.11"
```

Answer (score 3):

I hit this same problem on my machine this week. I was having inconsistent results to others in my team too.

In my case, the problem was that:

1. I had installed multiple Python versions with `brew`.
2. I had installed `pipenv` when my Python version was 3.10.

When I ran:

```bash
head $(which pipenv)
```

I saw a reference to ...`python3.10`... in the shebang line.

If you see something similar, you might have the same problem and I was able to resolve with the following:

```bash
brew uninstall python@3.10
brew install pipenv
brew link --overwrite pipenv
```

now `head $(which pipenv)` shows no hardcoded reference to python3.10 and instead uses a Python version relative to its own directory, but from here I was able to:

```bash
pipenv --rm
pipenv shell
pipenv install
```

and everything worked as expected. Leaving this here for reference for anyone else that's having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Working off of @dom-hastings answer, all I had to do was `pipenv --rm` then `pipenv install` and `pipenv shell` and everything was happy again.

Seems like when I did `pipenv shell` first, it may have caused this mess in the first place but hard to tell for sure.  I typically do `pipenv install` followed by `pipenv shell` and typically do not experience any issues.